# Making comparing 2 tables faster (Postgres/SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.6

I wrote a code in python to manipulate a table I have in my database. I am doing so using SQL Alchemy. Basically I have table 1 that has 2 500 000 entries. I have another table 2 with 200 000 entries. Basically what I am trying to do, is compare my source ip and dest ip in table 1 with source ip and dest ip in table 2. if there is a match, I replace the ip source and ip dest in table 1 with a data that matches ip source and ip dest in table 2 and I add the entry in table 3. My code also checks if the entry isn't already in the new table. If so, it skips it and then goes on with the next row.
My problem is its extremely slow. I launched my script yesterday and in 24 hours it only went through 47 000 entries out of 2 500 000. I am wondering if there are anyways I can speed up the process. It's a postgres db and I can't tell if the script taking this much time is reasonable or if something is up. If anyone had a similar experience with something like this, how much time did it take before completion ?
Many thanks.

```
session = Session()
i = 0
start_id = 1
flows = session.query(Table1).filter(Table1.id >= start_id).all()
result_number = len(flows)
vlan_list = {"['0050']", "['0130']", "['0120']", "['0011']", "['0110']"}
while i < result_number:
    for flow in flows:
        if flow.vlan_destination in vlan_list:
            usage = session.query(Table2).filter(Table2.ip ==
                                                                                     str(flow.ip_destination)).all()
            if len(usage) > 0:
                usage = usage[0].usage
            else:
                usage = str(flow.ip_destination)
            usage_ip_src = session.query(Table2).filter(Table2.ip ==
                                                                                                    str(flow.ip_source)).all()
            if len(usage_ip_src) > 0:
                usage_ip_src = usage_ip_src[0].usage
            else:
                usage_ip_src = str(flow.ip_source)
            if flow.protocol == "17":
                protocol = func.REPLACE(flow.protocol, "17", 'UDP')
            elif flow.protocol == "1":
                protocol = func.REPLACE(flow.protocol, "1", 'ICMP')
            elif flow.protocol == "6":
                protocol = func.REPLACE(flow.protocol, "6", 'TCP')
            else:
                protocol = flow.protocol
            is_in_db = session.query(Table3).filter(Table3.protocol ==
                                                                                            protocol)\
                .filter(Table3.application == flow.application)\
                .filter(Table3.destination_port == flow.destination_port)\
                .filter(Table3.vlan_destination == flow.vlan_destination)\
                .filter(Table3.usage_source == usage_ip_src)\
                .filter(Table3.state == flow.state)\
                .filter(Table3.usage_destination == usage).count()
            if is_in_db == 0:
                to_add = Table3(usage_ip_src, usage, protocol, flow.application, flow.destination_port,
                                                flow.vlan_destination, flow.state)
                session.add(to_add)
                session.flush()
                session.commit()
                print("added " + str(i))
            else:
                print("usage already in DB")
        i = i + 1

session.close()
```

**EDIT** As requested, here are more details : Table 1 has 11 columns, the two we are interested in are source ip and dest ip.
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfrRN.png)
Here, I have Table 2 :[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp1iG.png). It has an IP and a Usage. What my script is doing is that it takes source ip and dest ip from table one and looks up if there is a match in Table 2. If so, it replaces the ip address by usage, and adds this along with some of the columns of Table 1 in Table 3 :[Table3][3]
Along doing this, when adding the protocol column into Table 3, it writes the protocol name instead of the number, just to make it more readable.

**EDIT 2** I am trying to think about this differently, so I did a diagram of my problem [Diagram (X problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zj72.png)
What I am trying to figure out is if my code (Y solution) is working as intended. I've been coding in python for a month only and I feel like I am messing something up. My code is supposed to take every row from my Table 1, compare it to Table 2 and add data to table 3. My Table one has over 2 million entries and it's understandable that it should take a while but its too slow. For example, when I had to load the data from the API to the db, it went faster than the comparisons im trying to do with everything that is already in the db. I am running my code on a virtual machine that has sufficient memory so I am sure it's my code that is lacking and I need direction to as what can be improved. Screenshots of my tables:

Table 2
[image: Table2]

Table 3
[image: Table3]

Table 1
[image: Table1]

**EDIT 3** : Postgresql QUERY

```sql
SELECT
  coalesce(table2_1.usage, table1.ip_source) AS coalesce_1,
  coalesce(table2_2.usage, table1.ip_destination) AS coalesce_2,
  CASE table1.protocol WHEN %(param_1) s THEN %(param_2) s WHEN %(param_3) s THEN %(param_4) s WHEN %(param_5) s THEN %(param_6) s ELSE table1.protocol END AS anon_1,
  table1.application AS table1_application,
  table1.destination_port AS table1_destination_port,
  table1.vlan_destination AS table1_vlan_destination,
  table1.state AS table1_state
FROM
  table1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS table2_2 ON table2_2.ip = table1.ip_destination
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS table2_1 ON table2_1.ip = table1.ip_source
WHERE
  table1.vlan_destination IN (
    %(vlan_destination_1) s,
    %(vlan_destination_2) s,
    %(vlan_destination_3) s,
    %(vlan_destination_4) s,
    %(vlan_destination_5) s
  )
  AND NOT (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        table3
      WHERE
        table3.usage_source = coalesce(table2_1.usage, table1.ip_source)
        AND table3.usage_destination = coalesce(table2_2.usage, table1.ip_destination)
        AND table3.protocol = CASE table1.protocol WHEN %(param_1) s THEN %(param_2) s WHEN %(param_3) s THEN %(param_4) s WHEN %(param_5) s THEN %(param_6) s ELSE table1.protocol END
        AND table3.application = table1.application
        AND table3.destination_port = table1.destination_port
        AND table3.vlan_destination = table1.vlan_destination
        AND table3.state = table1.state
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for reaching ! I will put an example of what is expected in my new table. I put that as a way to signal to my code to stop running once its done, when it reaches the end of Table1.

Comment: Okay so what I should do is modify my line and go for something like flows = session.query(Table1).filter(Table1.id >= start_id).limit(100).all() ?

Comment: Edited my post, please let me know if it needs more details or more info

Comment: I'm with Ilja. Even after editing, your question still does not contain enough details to give an informed answer. It also looks like an XY solution to me. Maybe try to look at it from a different angle and edit the way you pose the question. Also, seeing the models as screenshots is not optimal. You even left out some columns that you use in the code. I see many places to improve this. But without clearly understanding the expected outcome it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I edited my post trying to re-think about the problem im having. I added a diagram that has an outline of how I went thinking about it, with all the columns that are in the code, hopefully it's a bit better

Comment: also added screenshots from my tables directly from the database !

Comment: Also, from the description of your business task, make sure that your tables have a compound index on (source_ip, dest_ip).

Comment: Thank you, i'm looking this up. I think that I can do much when it comes to changing the code, but maybe fixing by choosing good index will help. Though I want to ask, will I have to reload everything into the db when changing my index ?

Comment: What is the type of `vlan_destination` in the database? And where does it come from? It looks a lot like the string representation of a Python list. If that is true, you should consider either converting it to an array type in the database as well (or using normalized schema).

Comment: it's a string type ! Will do

Answer (score 1):

Given the current question, I think this at least comes close to what you might be after. The idea is to perform the entire operation in the database, instead of fetching everything – the whole 2,500,000 rows – and filtering in Python etc.:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, case
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased


def newhotness(session, vlan_list):
    # The query needs to join Table2 twice, so it has to be aliased
    dst = aliased(Table2)
    src = aliased(Table2)

    # Prepare required SQL expressions
    usage = func.coalesce(dst.usage, Table1.ip_destination)
    usage_ip_src = func.coalesce(src.usage, Table1.ip_source)
    protocol = case({"17": "UDP",
                     "1": "ICMP",
                     "6": "TCP"},
                    value=Table1.protocol,
                    else_=Table1.protocol)

    # Form a query producing the data to insert to Table3
    flows = session.query(
            usage_ip_src,
            usage,
            protocol,
            Table1.application,
            Table1.destination_port,
            Table1.vlan_destination,
            Table1.state).\
        outerjoin(dst, dst.ip == Table1.ip_destination).\
        outerjoin(src, src.ip == Table1.ip_source).\
        filter(Table1.vlan_destination.in_(vlan_list),
               ~session.query(Table3).
                   filter_by(usage_source=usage_ip_src,
                             usage_destination=usage,
                             protocol=protocol,
                             application=Table1.application,
                             destination_port=Table1.destination_port,
                             vlan_destination=Table1.vlan_destination,
                             state=Table1.state).
                   exists())

    stmt = insert(Table3).from_select(
        ["usage_source", "usage_destination", "protocol", "application",
         "destination_port", "vlan_destination", "state"],
        flows)

    return session.execute(stmt)
```

If the `vlan_list` is selective, or in other words filters out most rows, this will perform *a lot less* operations in the database. Depending on the size of `Table2` you may benefit from indexing `Table2.ip`, but do test first. If it is relatively small, I would guess that PostgreSQL will perform a hash or nested loop join there. If some column of the ones used to filter out duplicates in `Table3` is unique, you could perform an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING` instead of removing duplicates in the `SELECT` using the `NOT EXISTS` subquery expression (which PostgreSQL will perform as an antijoin). If there is a possibility that the `flows` query may produce duplicates, add a call to `Query.distinct()` to it.

Comment: That did the trick !! Only had to add a query distinct to avoid duplicates and my code ran in a split second instead of literal hours. Thank you so much !!